# Can't find element with Xpath (Selenium with Jest)

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, xpath, jestjs

I just trying test a website with selenium and jest. But when i use  `driver.findElement(By.xpath())` the method can't find element. And issued an error like this

```
 NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/button[2]"}   
      (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)

      31 | 
      32 |         await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[2]/button`)).click();
    > 33 |         await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/button[2]`)).click();
```

And here my code

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {By, until, Navigation, Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
const chrome = require ('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const assert = require('assert');

describe('Test Login with Jest', function() {

    let driver;
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    beforeAll(async () => {
        chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());
        driver = await new Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();

    });

    afterAll(async () => {
        await driver.quit();
    });

    it("SEMANGAT GUH !", async () => {
        await driver.get("https://genflix.co.id");

        let titleGenflix = await driver.getTitle();

        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[2]/button`)).click();
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/button[2]`)).click();
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="email"]`)).sendKeys("my_email");
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="password"]`)).sendKeys("my_password");
        await driver.findElement(By.xpath(`/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/button`)).click();

        assert.equal(titleGenflix, "Genflix");


    }, 10000);
});
```

I hope someone can help me,
Thank you

Comment: Please always remove your login credentials from your script.

Comment: @E.Wiest thank you for reminding me and also to edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clues. Change your code and use relative XPath to click on the `login` button (use `until` conditions and `executeScript` to perform the click) :

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//button[.='Login']")),10000);
let logb= await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[.='Login']"));
await driver.wait(until.elementIsEnabled(logb,10000));
await driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",logb);
```

Do the same for the rest of your script (even for the senddkeys actions (until located> until enabled > click > sendkeys)). And preferably use relative XPath :

```
//button[.="Login"]
//button[.="Login with Email/UserID"]
//input[@id="email"]
//input[@id="password"]
//button[@type="submit"]
```

Side note : you can start directly from the following url to perform the login step (and remove your 2 first clicks):

```
https://genflix.co.id/login/email
```